# Centering numbers in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I would like to generate table which looks approximately (not necessarily) like

[image]

If you have any suggestion for this sort of data representation, don't hesitate to tell. So far I have come up with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}   


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \captionsetup
  {
  singlelinecheck = off,
  justification   = raggedright,
  labelfont       = bf,
  }
  \begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}    
    \caption{ABC}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l SSSSSSSSS }
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{l}{2010} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{2011} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{2012} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{2013} \\
      \cmidrule{2-9}
    Name    & {bil}~\$ & \% & {bil}~\$ & \% & {bil}~\$ & \%     & {bil}~\$ & \%   \\ 
    \midrule
    {Aaaaaaaaaaaa}  &  20 456 & 1.2 &    20150 & 90.5 & 20150 & 90.5 & 20150 & 90.5    \\
    {Bbbbbbb}       & 5 256 & 21.3  \\  
    {Ccccccc}       & 58 & 0.5 \\
    {Dddd}          & 125 000\\
    {Eeeeeeeeeee}   & \\
    {FFFFFF}        & \\
    {ggggggg}       & \\
    \bottomrule
    $\sum$      & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \medskip \noindent Reference: John Johnson
    \label{1111}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which unfortunately results in two problems:

1. it doesn't center the data entries, nor the columns' names "year", "bil $" and "%" right
2. table is too wide. Should I decrease font size in the table or is there anything better to do?

EDIT: Another code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}   


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccc}

\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{2010}    &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{2011}    &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{2012}    &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{2013}    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}

 &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{bil~\$} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\%}     &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{bil~\$} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\%}     &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{bil~\$} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\%}     &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{bil~\$} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\%}      \\
\midrule



{Aaaaaaaaaaaa}  &  20 456 & 1.2  &  20 456 & 1.2 &  20 456 & 1.2 &  20 456 & 1.2   \\
    {Bbbbbbb}       & 5 256 & 21.3 & 5 256 & 21.3& 5 256 & 21.3& 5 256 & 21.3  \\  
    {Ccccccc}       & 58 & 0.5 & 58 & 0.5& 58 & 0.5& 58 & 0.5 \\
    {Dddd}          & 125 000 \\
    {Eeeeeeeeeee}   & \\
    {FFFFFF}        & \\
    {ggggggg}       & \\
\bottomrule
{$\sum$} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a pro in this area, but here is a workaround.

- First of all, to avoid the large width of the table, you can tell `siunitx` what are those columns supposed to be. `*{4}{…}` is just to avoid writing four times the same. And `S[table-format = 5.0, group-minimum-digits = 3] S[table-format = 2.1]` means that the first column has numbers with 5 digits before the comma and none after and the second column two digits before and one after. The `group-minimum-digits = 3`, as suggested by egreg, tells `siunitx` to add a *space* after every three digits (even if the number has only 4 digits).
- To center the cells you have to enclose them in `{}` (see `siunitx` documentation).

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{
        singlelinecheck = off,
        justification = raggedright,
        labelfont = bf,
    }
    \begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
        \caption{ABC}%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l *{4}{S[table-format = 5.0, group-minimum-digits = 3] S[table-format = 2.1]} }
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2010} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2011} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2012} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2013} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
            Name & {bil \$} & {\%} & {bil \$} & {\%} & {bil \$} & {\%} & {bil \$} & {\%} \\ 
            \midrule
            Aaaaaaaaaaaa & 20 456 & 1.2 & 20150 & 90.5 & 20150 & 90.5 & 20150 & 90.5 \\
            Bbbbbbb & 5256 & 21.3 \\ 
            Ccccccc & 58 & 0.5 \\
            Dddd & 125 000\\
            Eeeeeeeeeee & \\
            FFFFFF & \\
            ggggggg & \\
            \bottomrule
            $\sum$ & \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}

        \medskip \noindent Reference: John Johnson
        \label{1111}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably, in such a case, also 5256 should have the separator after the third digit from the right.

Comment: @egreg I don't know how to fix that apart from manually.

Comment: @Manuel: It does look good. However, when I use for example {Aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aa} instead of {Aaaaaaaaaaaa}, the table is still wide (I should have mentioned that in the original post). Probably the easiest way to repair this is changing font size. Any idea on that?___ Speaking of 5256, ~ as an invisible character doesn't work.

Comment: @Vochmelka then instead of using `l` column you can use `p{3cm}`.

Comment: `group-minimum-digits=3` in the specification for the column should do.

Comment: `\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=3}` worked well!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, egreg. @Vochmelka I wouldn't use that. In case you need to write, e.g., `\num{1000}` the package will space it up. And I think it shouldn't. You only need to space the numbers in THAT column to get a correct alignment. See my edit.